# Range.Find-Function - different results for similar values

Tags: excel, vba, function, find, runtime-error

I have written a Function to return the Long name of a 3 character string, so in Worksheet "List" there's 2 columns:
Column 1: List Short
Column 2: List Long

Similar to a VLOOKUP, my function shall find the Short and return the Long name.
However, there's something really strange happening:

Line 683 has Short = "Hlm" - and the function returns the correct Long from Lists Column B
Line 684 has Short = "Hlm" - but the function returns a runtime error 91.

```
Function GetList(ByRef ListShort, DataSource As Workbook)
    Dim Lists As Worksheet, ListShort As String
    Set Lists = DataSource.Worksheets("Lists")
    GetList = Lists.Cells.Find(ListShort, After:=Lists.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Offset(0, 1)
End Function
```

The error occurs in Line 4 of my code, runtime error 91 means that GetFile could not be declared.

Someone an idea what's the cause of this?

TIA! Marvin

Checked official documentation, revewed code w debugger, tried If commands to work around "Hml" value...

Comment: runtime error 91 means "Object variable not set". How do you call the function? Is `DataSource` set to something? Also note that you can't declare a variable with the same name as a parameter (`ListShort`), so your code doesn't compile at all.

Comment: Your code assumes that the `Find` succeeded. The error suggests it didn't.

Comment: Not related to your error but this won't ever return the second instance of Hlm.

Comment: Make sure you're not comparing upper case i (I) with lower case L (l). Both look very similar.

Comment: Probably worth adding the `LookAt` (`xlWhole`/`xlPart`) argument when you call `Find()`

Comment: Hi! 
Thanks for your quick replies, I rewrote the code and used VLookup.

Funny thing is, it still occurs. I have 19 vorrect values and 40 times #NV 
Also right now, on the worksheet, Strg-F doesnt Find "Hml" neither, but it is there.

Comment: It's Error 2042, I'll work from here Thanks to the community! <3

Comment: The parameter: ByRef ListShort, has the same name with local variable: ListShort As String

Comment: "ByRef ListShort, has the same name with local variable: ListShort As String" 

Yeah that's right, I edited the code to simplify it before pasting it here ^^

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, that's a good hint. (I'm only coding vba since november whenever I find time next to my normal tasks ^^)